# How to put not Route element inside createBrowserRouter in router-dom v6.15.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I tried to create react app using router dom and stuck in problem, i have that `App` component:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div id="page">
            <Sidebar />
            <SearchField />
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

and that `router` config:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
    [

    {
        path: "city/:cityName",
        element: (
            <WeatherContent />
        )
    },
    {
        path: "cities",
        element: (
            <WeatherContent />
        )
    },
    {
        path: "settings",
        element: (
            <WeatherContent />
        )
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        loader: () => {
            throw redirect("city/New%20York")
        },
        element: (
            <></>
        ),
    },
    {
        path: "*",
        element: (
            <div>
                <h1>Error 404</h1>
                <h2>page not found</h2>
                <Link to="home">Go back home</Link>
            </div>
        ),
    }
]);
```

and my `Sidebar` and `SearchField` components have `Link`'s from router dom, so i don't know where should i put them, so they would exist on every page and woun't throw errors, can someone help me with that?

i've tried to put `path: '/'` element as first, remove redirect from there and put `Sidebar` and `SearchField` inside, like that:

```
{
    path: "/",
    element: (
        <>
            <Sidebar />
            <SearchField />
        </>
    ),
}
```

but that doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `Sidebar` and `SearchField` components inside a Layout component and use [`<Outlet>`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) component to render their child route elements. Also, see [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.15.0/route/route#layout-routes)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Outlet, Link, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Sidebar = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>This is sidebar</h1>
    <Link to="/cities">cities</Link>
  </div>
);
const SearchField = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>This is search field</h1>
  </div>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Sidebar />
      <SearchField />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "city/:cityName",
        element: <div>city by name</div>
      },
      {
        path: "cities",
        element: <div>cities</div>
      },
      {
        path: "settings",
        element: <div>settings</div>
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        element: (
          <div>
            <h1>Error 404</h1>
            <h2>page not found</h2>
            <Link to="home">Go back home</Link>
          </div>
        )
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76902437-wq25xy?file=/src/App.tsx)